# Magento2 - InstallData Cms Page with content from file

Tags: magento2, phtml, cms-pages, installdata

as the title suggests

I'm creating a module that programmatically installs pages on cms_page,
my problem arises when I want to load the contents of a phtml file and pass it as html into the array to fill the content index ...

I have not very clear the path of where to put the phtml file and how to recall it indicating that path ....

example of the current structure

```
app
 | - code
 |    |- MyVendor
 |        |- MyModule
 |            |- registration.php
 |            |- etc
 |                |- module.xml
 |            |- Setup
 |                 |- InstallData.php
 |            |- view
 |                 |- frontend
 |                      |- templates
 |                           |- homepage.phtml
```

is the above path right?
who can write me the path of where to insert the phtml files and how to recall them?

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Setup;
use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $pageFactory;

public function __construct(PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
}

/**
 * Installs data for a module
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    // Load cms page by identifier
    $cmsPage = $this->_pageFactory->create()->load('home-page', 'identifier');

    $content = '<div id="something">
                {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="home-page" template="app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/homepage.phtml" }}
                </div>';


    // Create CMS Page
    if (!$cmsPage->getId()) {
        $cmsPageData = [
            'title' => 'Custom cms page', // cms page title
            'page_layout' => '1column', // cms page layout
            'meta_keywords' => 'Page keywords', // cms page meta keywords
            'meta_description' => 'Page description', // cms page description
            'identifier' => 'home-page', // cms page url identifier
            'content_heading' => 'Custom Home page', // Page heading
            'content' => $content, // page content
            'is_active' => 1, // define active status
            'stores' => [0], // assign to stores
            'sort_order' => 0 // page sort order
        ];

        $this->_pageFactory->create()->setData($cmsPageData)->save();
    }
}
}
```

After apply the suggested changes
RETURN ERROR:

```
main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/homepage.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\ValidatorException(code: 0): Invalid template file: 'app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/homepage.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\\framework\\view\\element\\template_0' at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:277)"} []
```

Comment: app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/mypage.phtml

Comment: return error Invalid template file

Answer (score 0):

You need to write Phtml in path:

```
**app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/mypage.phtml**
```

And also recommended this [link](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-cms-pages-programmatically.html) for further Problem.

Comment: ok thanks, done.
but to load it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try letting the cms logic do the work.

Setup script as demonstrated in other answer.

Content something like this

```
<div id="something">
    {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="path/to/my/file.phtml" }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, now have used inside the InstallData.php your code but when i load the page return me this error:

Invalid template file: 'app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/homepage.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'